# Need to iterate backwards over a linux path

Tags: linux, bash, shell

0

I have a script that would have multiple paths (folder names).

Each folder path would have a Dockerfile, but its uncertain at what level that file would exist.

Lets say my path is **"v1/airflow/1.86/src/code/"**

Bu the file can be at Like for eg **"v1/airflow/1.86/src/Dockerfile"** or it can be at **"v1/airflow/1.86/Dockerfile"**

so i am trying to figure out a way where i can take a step back or cd ../ check recursively if the file exist there, if not then go one directory back, and look again and if it does, stop looking further

Any help is appreciated

I was looking a AWK for it, but nothing useful came out of it

Comment: You could probably pipe the output of ls into `grep` and then if no file is found, it runs `cd ..`

Comment: @CootMoon but how would it keep iterating backwards, thats the main problem

Comment: I figured out a solution that could work. You might need to add in a counter so it doesn't recurse for ever.

Comment: This was not exactly what i was looking out for,
But was able to leverage this and came up with a different strategy, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! [ -f "File.txt" ]; do
    echo "file not found!"
    cd ..
done
echo "file found!"
```

At the end of the loop you will be in the directory with the file. You might want to add a counter that exits the while loop after X iterations so it doesn't become an infinite loop if the file doesn't exist.